# How Can I get responses from api request using brearer token in laravel?

Tags: laravel, api, token, bearer-token

Problem description:

- I have a berer api. I just need to pass requests using a controller
  that actually makes requests and  receives the responses. ( NB:
  without using Postman )

My API root is like this : `http://localhost/cloud/website/api/v1/`

In api.php

```
        Route::group(['prefix' => 'v1'], function() {
            Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:sanctum'], function() {
                 Route::post('entries/sync-info', [EntrySyncInfoController::class, 'index']);
    }
 }
```

I am trying to get a response from  API but keep getting 500 SERVER ERROR.

```
    $token  ='24|cbG3w1ONkxxeUBhLCGwFjOSLk......';
    
    $response = $client->request('GET', 'http://localhost/cloud/website/api/v1/entries?perPage=50', [
    'headers' => [
        'Authorization' => 'Bearer '.$token,
        'Accept' => 'application/json',
    ],
]);

return $response->body();
```

But when I request on Postman then it gives me a response perfectly.

[postman request's image is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/21P6u.png)

Also when I hit this url directly on browser it says same error.

I also follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57037591/laravel-own-api-consumption-from-controller-with-bearer-token?rq=1) issue. it returns null.

How can I solve this issue? How can I get responses using bearer token?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$response = $client->get('http://localhost/cloud/website/api/v1/entries?perPage=50', [
    'headers' => [
        'Authorization' => 'Bearer '.$token,
        'Accept' => 'application/json',
    ],
]);
```

**Ref:** see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22355828/doing-http-requests-from-laravel-to-an-external-api),
also take a look at [this](https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/)

Comment: Thanks @moinul-robin brother  for your references. your references and [this link](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/http-client) helped me to solve the issue.